# Mocking and testing require.resolve calls in jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I want to mock a node's built-in function `require.resolve` in jest test suite. Here a working example of a problem [on repl.it](https://repl.it/@Rulsky/LightgreenPerfectAddax) and the code itself:

Test subject (as an example):

```
const requirer = () => {
  try {
    return require.resolve('./add')
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('failed to find a module')
  }
}

module.exports = requirer
```

Test suite:

```
const requirer = require('./requirer')

describe('attempt to mock require.resolve', () => {
   it('does not work', () => {
     require.resolve = jest.fn(arg => `./${arg}`)
     console.log(
       'is require.resolve mocked',
       jest.isMockFunction(require.resolve)) // will say true

     requirer()

     expect(require.resolve).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
     expect(require.resolve).toBeCalledWith('')
  })
})
```

Inside of a test suite declaration everything is OK (see an output of a `jest.isMockFunction(require.resolve)`) and mock works. But for a test subject `require.resolve` remains with original functionality.

Due to this issue, this isn't pure unit test.

If I, for example, mock `process.exit` everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

So, not a perfect solution, but it is simpler to inject (DI) require.resolve into

```
const requirer = (resolver) => {
  try {
    return resolver('./add')
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('failed to find a module')
  }
}

module.exports = requirer
```

now in a test suite passing down mocked version of a `require.resolve` works as expected

const requirer = require('./requirer')

```
describe('attempt to mock require.resolve', () => {
   it('works', () => {
     require.resolve = jest.fn(arg => `./${arg}`)
     console.log(
       'is require.resolve mocked',
       jest.isMockFunction(require.resolve)) // will say true

     requirer(require.resolve)

     expect(require.resolve).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
     // expect(require.resolve).toBeCalledWith('')
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's not exactly what you're looking for, but here's my workaround to be able to "mock" `require.resolve`.
There's an interesting feature in jest allowing you to define your own module resolver:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#resolver-string

Having that in mind, here is, basically, what I've done:

- I created my own resolver like so:

```js
const glob = require('glob');

let mapping = {};

// Looks for "module-resolution.json" files in all the `__tests__` directories
glob
  .sync(`${__dirname}/../../packages/**/src/**/__tests__/modules-resolution.json`)
  .forEach((file) => {
    // For each of them, merges them in the "mapping" object
    mapping = { ...mapping, ...require(file) };
  });

function resolver(path, options) {
  // If the path corresponds to a key in the mapping object, returns the fakely resolved path
  // otherwise it calls the Jest's default resolver
  return mapping[path] || options.defaultResolver(path, options);
}

module.exports = resolver;
```

- Then, I configured it in my jest config file:

```js
module.exports = {
  roots: ['<rootDir>'],
  testMatch: ['<rootDir>/packages/**/__tests__/**/*.test.js'],
  collectCoverageFrom: ['packages/**/src/**/*.js', '!packages/**/src/__tests__/**'],
  resolver: '<rootDir>/test-utils/resolver',
};
```

- Finally, I can create `modules-resolution.json` files in my test folders that look like this:

```
{
  "fake-module": "/path/to/fake-module"
}
```

This do the job for me so far and I think that, starting from this example, we could do something more complex but more developer friendly !
Of course, that would be even better if this featured could be directly included in jest !
Anyway, I hope this will help some of you