# Jest: mock require.resolve calls

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47907454/mocking-and-testing-require-resolve-calls-in-jest) but no one has answered it as directly as I'd like so here we go again:

### How do I mock calls to `require.resolve`?

So if I have a module like so:

`get-module.js`

```js
// just a simple example, don't get too caught up
export default getModuleLocation() {
  return require.resolve('./my-module');
}
```

How can I make my `require.resolve` call return something else? Here's what I've tried:

`get-module.test.js`

```js
import getModule from './get-module';

let originalRequireResolve;
beforeAll(() => {
  originalRequireResolve = require.resolve;
  require.resolve = jest.fn();
});

afterAll(() => {
  require.resolve = originalRequireResolve;
});

it('gets the module', () => {
  //  this does NOT work
  require.resolve.mockReturnValueOnce('mock-module');
  expect(getModule()).toBe('mock-module');
});
```

The above does *not* work but the example does a good job of communicating what I'm trying to do. It seems like `require` is some sort of reserved thing I can't mock.

Any ideas? No workarounds please.